# mysql big query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I'd need to optimize the following query which takes up to 10 minutes to run. 
Performing the explain it seems to be running on all 350815 rows of the "table_3" table and 1 for all the others. 
General rules to place indexes the propper way? Should I think about using multidimensional indexes? Where should I use them at first on the JOINS, the WHERE or the GROUP BY, if I remember right there should be a hierarchy to follow. Also If I have 1 row for all tables but one (in the row column of the explain table) how can I optimize usually my optimization consists in ending up with only one row for all columns but one. 
All tables average from 100k to 1000k+ rows.

```
CREATE TABLE datab1.sku_performance
SELECT 
      table1.sku,
      CONCAT(table1.sku,' ',table1.fk_container ) as sku_container,
      table1.price as price,
      SUM( CASE WHEN ( table1.fk_table1_status = 82 
                    OR table1.fk_table1_status = 119 
                    OR table1.fk_table1_status = 124 
                    OR table1.fk_table1_status = 141 
                    OR table1.fk_table1_status = 131) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            / COUNT( DISTINCT id_catalog_school_class) as qty_returned,
      SUM( CASE WHEN ( table1.fk_table1_status In (23,13,44,65,6,75,8,171,12,166)) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            / COUNT( DISTINCT id_catalog_school_class) as qt,
      container.id_container as container_id,
      container.idden as container_idden,
      container.delivery_badge,
      catalog_school.id_catalog_school,
      LEFT(catalog_school.flight_fair,2) as departing_country,
      catalog_school.weight,
      catalog_school.flight_type,
      catalog_school.price,
      table_3.id_table_3,
      table_3.fk_catalog_brand,
      MAX( LEFT( table_3.note,3 )) AS supplier,
      GROUP_CONCAT( product_number, ' by ',FORMAT(catalog_school_class.quantity,0)  
          ORDER BY product_number ASC SEPARATOR ' + ') as supplier_prod,
      Sum( distinct( catalog_school_class.purch_pri * catalog_school_class.quantity)) AS final_purch_pri,
      catalog_groupp.idden as supplier_idden,
      catalog_category_details.id_catalog_category,
      catalog_category_details.cat1 as product_cat1,
      catalog_category_details.cat2 as product_cat2,
      COUNT( distinct catalog_school_class.id_catalog_school_class) as setinfo, 
      datab1.pageviewgrouped.pv as page_views, 
      Sum(distinct(catalog_school_class.purch_pri * catalog_school_class.quantity)) AS purch_pri, 
      container_has_table_3.position, 
      max( table1.created_at ) as last_order_date
   FROM
      table1
         LEFT JOIN container 
            ON table1.fk_container = container.id_container
         LEFT JOIN catalog_school 
            ON table1.sku = catalog_school.sku
            LEFT JOIN table_3 
               ON catalog_school.fk_table_3 = table_3.id_table_3
               LEFT JOIN container_has_table_3  
                  ON table_3.id_table_3 = container_has_table_3.fk_table_3
               LEFT JOIN datab1.pageviewgrouped 
                  on table_3.id_table_3 = datab1.pageviewgrouped.url
                  LEFT JOIN datab1.catalog_category_details 
                     ON datab1.catalog_category_details.id_catalog_category = table_3_has_catalog_minority.fk_catalog_category
               LEFT JOIN catalog_groupp 
                     ON table_3.fk_catalog_groupp = catalog_groupp.id_catalog_groupp
               LEFT JOIN table_3_has_catalog_minority 
                  ON table_3.id_table_3 = table_3_has_catalog_minority.fk_table_3
            LEFT JOIN catalog_school_class 
               ON catalog_school.id_catalog_school = catalog_school_class.fk_catalog_school
   WHERE
          table_3.status_ok = 1
      AND catalog_school.status = 'active'
      AND table_3_has_catalog_minority.is_primary = '1'
   GROUP BY 
      table1.sku, 
      table1.fk_container;
```

[image]

rows per table :

```
.table1 960096 to 1.3mn rows
.container 9275 to 13000 rows
.catalog_school 709970 to 1 mn rows
.table_3 709970 to 1 mn rows
.container_has_table_3 709970 to 1 mn rows
.pageviewgrouped 500000 rows
.catalog_school_class 709970 to 1 mn rows
.catalog_groupp 3000 rows
.table_3_has_catalog_minority  709970 to 1 mn rows
.catalog_category_details 659 rows
```

Comment: To optimize a query, **we need to see the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: What is going on here? `... WHERE table_3.status_ok = AND ...` It looks like something is missing.

Comment: While you are providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table involved, please tell us how big each table is.

Comment: Problem 1:  GROUP BY does not include all the non-aggregate expression in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Problem 2:  JOIN tends to inflate the number of rows in the intermediate table, then GROUP BY deflates it.  These are at cross-purposes; you should try to either avoid JOINs or avoid the GROUP BY.

Comment: (Problem 2 is not a problem _if_ all the JOINs are on the PRIMARY KEY in the right-hand table.)

Comment: Problem 3:  LEFT JOIN usually forces the left-hand table to be looked at first.  In your SELECT, this probably prevents the optimizer from using any of the WHERE clause for earlier filtering.  Can you get rid of `LEFT`?

Comment: @RickJames added explain and rows count per table

Comment: @AndyLester added explain and rows count per table

Comment: Still need SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Comment: How many rows in the resultset?  If it is a lot less than 350815, which table does the most filtering?  We should strive to get _that_ table earlier in the EXPLAIN.  Get rid of LEFT whereever you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much to put into a single comment, so I'll add here and adjust later as possibly needed...  You have LEFT JOINs everywhere, but your WHERE clause is specifically qualifying fields from the Table_3, Catalog_School and Table_3_has_catalog_minority.  This by default changes them to INNER JOINs.

With respect to your where clause

```
WHERE
          table_3.status_ok = 1
      AND catalog_school.status = 'active'
      AND table_3_has_catalog_minority.is_primary = '1'
```

Which table / column would have the smallest results based on these criteria.  ex: Table_3.Status_ok = 1 might have 500k records but table_3_has_catalog_minority.is_primary may only have 65k and catalog_school.status = 'active' may have 430k.

Also, some of your columns are not qualified with the table they are coming from.  Can you please confirm... such as "id_catalog_school_class" and "product_number"

SOMETIMES, changing the order of the tables, with good knowledge of the makeup of the data and in MySQL adding a "STRAIGHT_JOIN" keyword can improve performance.  This was something I've had in the past working with gov't database of contracts and grants with 20+ million records and joining to about 15+ lookup tables.  It went from hanging the server to getting the query finished in less than 2 hrs.  Considering the amount of data I was dealing with, that was actually a good time.

AFTER dissecting this thing some, I restructured a bit more for readability, added aliases for table references and changed the order of the query and have some suggested indexes.  To help the query, I tried moving the Catalog_School table to the first position and added the STRAIGHT_JOIN.  The index is based on the STATUS first to match the WHERE clause, THEN I included the SKU as it is first element of the GROUP BY, then the other columns used to join to the subsequent tables.  By having these columns in the index, it can qualify the joins without having to go to the raw data.

By changing the group by to the Catalog_School.SKU instead of table_1.SKU the index from catalog_school can be used to help optimize that.  It is the same value since the join from the catalog_school.sku = table_1.sku.  I also added index references for table_1 and table_3 that are suggestions -- again, to preemptively qualify the joins without going to the raw data pages of the tables.

I would be interested in knowing the final performance (better or worse) from your data.

```
TABLE             INDEX ON...
catalog_school    ( status, sku, fk_table_3, id_catalog_school )
table_1           ( sku, fk_container )      
table_3           ( id_table_3, status_ok, fk_catalog_groupp )

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      CS.sku,
      CONCAT(CS.sku,' ',T1.fk_container ) as sku_container,
      T1.price as price,
      SUM( CASE WHEN ( T1.fk_table1_status IN ( 82, 119, 124, 141, 131) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            / COUNT( DISTINCT CSC.id_catalog_school_class) as qty_returned,
      SUM( CASE WHEN ( T1.fk_table1_status In (23,13,44,65,6,75,8,171,12,166)) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            / COUNT( DISTINCT CSC.id_catalog_school_class) as qt,
      CS.id_catalog_school,
      LEFT(CS.flight_fair,2) as departing_country,
      CS.weight,
      CS.flight_type,
      CS.price,
      T3.id_table_3,
      T3.fk_catalog_brand,
      MAX( LEFT( T3.note,3 )) AS supplier,
      C.id_container as container_id,
      C.idden as container_idden,
      C.delivery_badge,
      GROUP_CONCAT( product_number, ' by ',FORMAT(CSC.quantity,0)  
          ORDER BY product_number ASC SEPARATOR ' + ') as supplier_prod,
      Sum( distinct( CSC.purch_pri * CSC.quantity)) AS final_purch_pri,
      CGP.idden as supplier_idden,
      CCD.id_catalog_category,
      CCD.cat1 as product_cat1,
      CCD.cat2 as product_cat2,
      COUNT( distinct CSC.id_catalog_school_class) as setinfo, 
      PVG.pv as page_views, 
      Sum(distinct(CSC.purch_pri * CSC.quantity)) AS purch_pri, 
      CHT3.position, 
      max( T1.created_at ) as last_order_date
   FROM
      catalog_school  CS

         JOIN table1 T1
            ON CS.sku = T1.sku
            LEFT JOIN container C
               ON T1.fk_container = C.id_container

         LEFT JOIN catalog_school_class  CSC
            ON CS.id_catalog_school = CSC.fk_catalog_school

         JOIN table_3  T3
            ON CS.fk_table_3 = T3.id_table_3
            JOIN table_3_has_catalog_minority T3HCM
               ON T3.id_table_3 = T3HCM.fk_table_3
               LEFT JOIN datab1.catalog_category_details  CCD
                  ON T3HCM.fk_catalog_category = CCD.id_catalog_category

            LEFT JOIN container_has_table_3  CHT3
               ON T3.id_table_3 = CHT3.fk_table_3

            LEFT JOIN datab1.pageviewgrouped  PVG
               on T3.id_table_3 = PVG.url

            LEFT JOIN catalog_groupp  CGP
               ON T3.fk_catalog_groupp = CGP.id_catalog_groupp
   WHERE
          CS.status = 'active'
      AND T3.status_ok = 1
      AND T3HCM.is_primary = '1'
   GROUP BY 
      CS.sku, 
      T1.fk_container;
```

Comment: @MarkoC, glad this answer appears to have worked / helped... but wondering what the final time of the query has been optimized to based on this input / suggestions... It also could help for others wondering what techniques have worked and how effective too.

Comment: Thanks, again as soon as I'll have finished my optimization I'll post the times! For the moment I am processing it and trying to go a bit further!